# My div goes further down the tab menus in asp.net mvc2 application

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I am making some custom tabs in asp.net. I am also using jquery, however I am overriding the default tab look. I ran into a small problem where a div(**#right-side**) I placed after an unordered list appears further down after the information related to a tab.

Please look at the diagram below :

[image]

In the **#left-side** I have my left curve section of the menu and then in **.tab-menu** I have a repeating 1 pixel picture and finally at **#right-side** I have the right curve section of my menu BUT it appears way **down**, towards the left side of the **save** button.

Any ideas to make the picture in the Actual **#right-side** appear in the **#right-side(supposed to appear)** position.

Thanks

Here is my code:

html

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="left-side">
    </div>
    <ul class="tab-menu">
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetHomeTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="home" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="dates-and-location" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetContactUsTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="tariff" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetHomeTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>

            <div id="customer-information" class="menu">
            </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetContactUsTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="rates-and-charges" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="payments-and-vouchers" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="delivery-and-collection" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetContactUsTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="general" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="equipment-and-other-drivers" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="vehicle-information" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetContactUsTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="customer-preferences" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Action("GetProductTab", "Home") %>" class="a"><b>
                <div id="customer-statistics" class="menu">
                </div>
            </b></a></li>      

    </ul>
    <div id="right-side">
            </div>
</div>
```

---

related css for the #right-side

```
#tabs #right-side
{
background-image: url('../Content/images/right_side.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right 8px;
height: 50px;
width: 7px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright folks, I used absolute positioning only for this **#right-side** div. Shown below is the CSS I have used :

```
#tabs #right-side
{
background-image: url('../Content/images/right_side.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right 8px;
position:absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 7px;
float: left;
top: 3px;
left: 670px;
}
```

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look : [Formatting DIVs](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/6ECBm/)

If you don't find it useful then please correct me.

Thank you.

Here,

> InnerDiv1 = #left-side
>   InnerDiv2 = #right-side
>   InnerDiv3 = .tab-menu

Comment: i am planning to use absolute positioning to position my #right-side. I took a look at the link. btw my tabs work well in dreamweaver. but in this Asp.net mvc2 application, there is some code which is generated when the web page is being viewed. Thks for the ans.